Vercel Not Navigating Correctly Between Pages After Deployment (Works Locally)
Issue Description:
I’m experiencing issues with navigation between pages after deploying my project on Vercel. The project works perfectly locally, and I can navigate between pages without any problems. However, after deploying to Vercel, some pages do not load or result in 404 errors when navigating.
Project Links:
GitHub Repository
https://github.com/FadyFathey/digitalize-v.2.git
Vercel Deployment:
https://digitalize-v-2.vercel.app/
Project Structure:
DIGITALIZE-V.2
├── AboutUs
│   └── html
│       └── digitalize
│           ├── assets
│           └── about.html
├── blogs
│   └── html
│       └── digitalize
│           ├── assets
│           └── blogs.html
├── blogs-details
│   └── html
│       └── digitalize
│           ├── assets
│           └── blog-details.html
├── contact us
│   └── html
│       └── digitalize
│           ├── assets
│           └── contact.html
├── ourServices
│   └── html
│       └── digitalize
│           ├── assets
│           └── service.html
└── vercel.json


Current vercel.json Configuration:
{
  "version": 2,
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/about",
      "destination": "/AboutUs/html/digitalize/about.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "/contact",
      "destination": "/contact us/html/digitalize/contact.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "/ourServices",
      "destination": "/ourServices/html/digitalize/service.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "/blogs",
      "destination": "/blogs/html/digitalize/blogs.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "/blog-details",
      "destination": "/blogs-details/html/digitalize/blog-details.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/html/digitalize/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "cleanUrls": true,
  "trailingSlash": false
}

What I’ve Tried So Far:
Modified vercel.json: I tried different configurations for the rewrites, but navigation between pages still doesn’t work as expected.
Verified Folder Structure: I confirmed that the folder structure on Vercel matches the local structure exactly.
Tested Links: Links work locally, but after deployment, Vercel does not recognize some pages.
I tried removing all rewrites except for "source": "/(.*)" as you recommended, but I’m still facing the same issue where the pages don’t navigate correctly and some routes return 404 errors
Question:
How can I configure vercel.json to ensure that navigation between pages works correctly after deployment? Are there specific rewrite configurations I’m missing to fix this navigation issue?

Have you tried removing all rewrites apart from "source": "/(.*)",?

@kieranlul
I tried removing all rewrites except for "source": "/(.*)" as you recommended, but I’m still facing the same issue where the pages don’t navigate correctly and some routes return 404 errors.
If possible, could we discuss this privately? I can provide temporary access to my Vercel account if needed.

Try the vercel.json in my answer.

Please try this as your vercel.json and let me know how it goes.
{
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/(.*)",
        "destination": "html/digitalize/index"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false
  }


You can add "version": 2, at the top if you would like as well. The main change is the removal of .html at the end the the destination path.

kieranlul same error 404  404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND ID: fra1:fra1::sd9lk-1730297702194-1ba8354418c1  @kieranlul

I'm still experiencing the same error after updating the vercel.json as recommended.  If you're open to it, would you be available for a quick meeting to help troubleshoot this live? I'm available at 9 PM if that works for you.     @kieranlul

Try removing ../.. in your hrefs so it is just <a href="/AboutUs/html/digitalize/about.html". I have tested on my sandbox with your setup and all working.

same error : 404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND ID: fra1:fra1::zqfnx-1730298645962-475e977962db  @kieranlul

Thank you for your continued help! I suspect that the sandbox environment might be different from the actual deployment on Vercel, as everything works locally for me with both absolute and relative paths. However, the issue persists on the Vercel server. @kieranlul

In your project settings on Vercel. Do you have "Include files outside the root directory" set to "ON"?

I checked my project settings, and "Include files outside the root directory" is already set to Enabled. However, I'm still experiencing the same issue with navigation between pages.
@kieranlul

Just to test for sanity. Create a new project from scratch with the same github repo and test. Could be a setting that has been changed while troubleshooting.

Thank you! I’ll set up a new project from scratch with the same GitHub repo and test it. I’ll update you here with the results . @kieranlul

If its easier then you can just clone the repo and connect the new project to that.

I created a new project from scratch as you suggested, using the same GitHub repo, and unfortunately, I'm still facing the same issue. Here’s the link to the new deployment: https://digitalize-test.vercel.app/.
Also, a quick question: in the Root Directory setting on Vercel, I currently have it set to html/digitalize. I believe this is correct, but I just wanted to confirm. Thanks again for all your help!

As you rewrite the index you should not have to put anything in the root directory so just leave that blank.

I followed your suggestion and left the Root Directory blank. The deployment works now in terms of navigation, but the CSS isn’t loading correctly across the pages. You can check the result here: https://digitalize-v-test.vercel.app/.

I see you got that sorted now. Well done.
